# User.php boot() method being called multiple times on user registration

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

When creating a user using the built-in Laravel 7 functionality I call the `boot()` method on my User model in order to assign a UUID to the new user. The issue I'm encountering is that the boot method get's called a total of 4 times for some reason causing 4 different directories to be created on S3.

App/User.php

```
/**
    * Create the user when this class is called
    *
    * @return void
    */
protected static function boot()
{
    // Setup parent
    parent::boot();

    // Create UUID
    $uuid = Str::uuid();

    // Create user directory on S3
    Storage::disk('s3')->makeDirectory('users/' . $uuid);

    // Assign UUID to new user
    self::creating(function ($model) use ($uuid) {
        $model->id = $uuid;
    });
}
```

Is this the proper way to be adding a field to a user on creation? I have tried to add it using the `RegisterController.php -> create()` method but then it would not add anything to the user and result in an error saying the ID requires a default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boot method is called whenever an *object* is to be created (not just persisted, which is what `creating` will do). This will happen whenever Laravel uses Auth functions, for instance, to get the current user, hence the multiple calls to boot.

You should place all the content in boot (apart from the `parent::boot()` call) inside the creating closure:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    // Setup parent
    parent::boot();

    self::creating(function ($model) {

        // Create UUID
        $uuid = Str::uuid();

        // Create user directory on S3
        Storage::disk('s3')->makeDirectory('users/' . $uuid);

        $model->id = $uuid;
    });
}
```

No need for the `use ($uuid)` on the function anymore.

Comment: Oh, and as a performance aside, you might want to turn your S3 directory creation into a queued job instead, otherwise user creation might be a little slow. Plus it makes it easier to rollback or cancel in case the creation of your user fails for another reason.